# Is it inappropriate to contact my Master’s supervisor on Facebook or Instagram for a reference while she’s on maternity leave?

Tags: advisor, recommendation-letter, email, united-kingdom

I am currently applying for a PhD degree in Canada and one of my potential supervisors from the UK asked if he could ask my Master’s supervisor for reference. So I emailed my ex-supervisor about this but got an automatic reply saying she’s on maternity leave.

However, I have her Facebook and Instagram info, so I can message her there, but is it appropriate to do so? She gave birth around three months ago, and we have not been in contact for around two years.

Comment: If you emailed her then you have already asked, actually. If she replies then she is willing. The auto bounce doesn't mean she hasn't seen it.

Comment: Are you actual friends on Facebook or do you happen to have the contact details?

Comment: @JackAidley we are friends on FB and Instagram but haven't actually sent messages after I graduate.

Comment: I think it depends what kind of relationship you had with her, did you used to message each other on Facebook/Instagram prior to not speaking with her for two years?

Comment: If she's not responding to professional email, what do you thing the chances are that she'd respond to private messaging?

Answer (score 75):

This is from an American perspective, not a British one, but absolutely do not message her on Facebook or Instagram! Especially if you have not been in touch for two years. I would never consider messaging a supervisor in such a way to ask for something professional, and that goes 10x while they are on official leave for any reason.

**Explain the situation to your potential supervisor and get in touch with your master's supervisor's department chair** or director of graduate studies for advice. They may know when her maternity leave is up or may be able to get in touch with her<sup>1</sup>. In the worst case, they can provide the best reference they can.

---

1: Some people on leave may be checking their email infrequently for matters like this. Of course, she is entitled not to, but they will know her personally and know whether she's open to requests like this or is entirely offline.

Comment: Thanks Azor I think you're right, I guess I will try ask the teaching assistant of the department first since she mentioned contacting the TA during her leave

Comment: @Pajxy No, the TA would be for her students, you don't need to contact them for this.

Comment: OP said that they actually are friend on Facebook, so the situation isn't the same as if he were contacting here out of the blue. It proves some kind of willingness to keep touch outside of work boundaries.

Comment: @Echox It doesn't matter, she is on official leave *from work*. That doesn't mean "try to contact me in other ways so I can do work." Asking for an informal reference is not life-and-death. Even if they occasionally chatted, it would still be inappropriate. And, honestly, depending on the writer, could harm your letter.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, writing a reference letter is *not* part of official "work". It is neither paid for, nor is it even mandatory! Hence, her official leave is only partially relevant here.

Comment: @Dilworth Most professors I know personally, and many on this site, describe it as part of their duties. Since professors are not paid hourly, I'm not sure you can say whether or not it is paid for. It's not mandatory in the same way deciding not to give someone an exemption to join your class is not required (i.e. it's using your professional judgement to decline).

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, *I* am a professor, and I don't see this as part of my "work". Also, I wouldn't care to get a message on FB. But this depends on the student, if I think they are good, friendly, respectful, etc. I also didn't understand your answer re mandatory: it's certainly not part of a paid duty.

Comment: @Dilworth Well then, we'll agree to disagree.

Comment: What does it have to do with American or British, it’s inappropriate period, thus the opening phrase seems strange and out of place.

Comment: @shalop Dunno, I'm not British! I think it's important to state our own limitations when answering a question

Comment: @Dilworth whether something is part of work (your work role) or not seems pretty simple to answer: would you do it if you didn't hold your work position? Could you even do it if you didn't have your work position (and in this case the work place relationship with OP)? If no, then it's part of your work. Going out with someone you know to talk about whatever -> not work related. Writing a reference for someone you worked with -> work related as no one would care if you weren't hired by your university and thereby were in the supervisor role.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- You might include the reasoning of why not to contact in the answer to make it more clear and allow people (OP and others) to judge whether the assumed context matches theirs. For instance, some might be known to mix private and work life more than you assume, or be known to not monitor their mail particularly regularly but be open to be directed to important mails via a more direct contact. (generally agree with your answer as default behaviour, but since OP is already facebook friends, they might know whether their supervisor/situation could be an exception to the rule)

Comment: @FrankHopkins, Actually this is not the "definition" of work. Work is what you are paid for and is part of your written *contract*. I'm unaware of any academic contract mandating writing letters for students (or even implying this is part of the obligations. Well, it simply isn't). As for your argument: indeed, even if someone is not a paid academic he/she can (and does at times) write letters (think Erdos!).

Comment: @Dilworth most contracts have a pretty loose "and reasonable tasks related to your role" sentence that would cover this. Not to mention that academic contracts and work definitions are even more loose than regular industry jobs. E.g. my work contract never had "give talks" or "write papers" in it either. but yes, if you want to argue with your employer the contract is your go-to place (along with any verbal agreements that are built on top); no one will force you to write student letters though as this is about deciding whether you write one. it's part of your professional scientific role

Comment: @Dilworth thus part of your work role if you're hired at a university/in a respective capacity. If you're not in such a job that backs that role obviously it's not part of your (regular) job (you might still have an honour association etc) but unless you have major credentials, no one cares about your recommendation letters if you write them in your private capacity as John Doe.

Comment: @FrankHopkins, again, writing letters is not part of your work because it's not mandatory. Publishing papers is mandatory and not doing so leads to losing one's job in most cases.

Comment: @Dilworth having a policy of never writing recommendation letters also gives you negative points at sane institutions. Most higher level jobs don't have a comprehensive list of mandatory duties. On the contrary, the definition of how to do such jobs well often is vague and implicit, because it's not easy to put into clear instructions. Anyway, we have different views here what's part of the job, just take into consideration when you interact with people that what for you is your private fun, for them is part of their work and thus they won't tolerate it intruding into their private life.

Comment: @FrankHopkins, maybe. But also being not a nice person (even outside work settings) "gives you negative points at 'sane' institutions". But being pleasant is still not a requirement of one's work.

Answer (score 19):

You have already used this person's professional email address, so your request is made.  She will check your email and respond to it when she is good and ready.  Many office workers set automated emails when they are on leave but continue to check email and deal with important matters; nevertheless, they are under no obligation to work while on leave.  It is not appropriate to badger an academic through their private email/social media while they are on leave (and doubly so since she's just had a baby).

The simplest thing to do here is to let this prospective supervisor know that you have contacted your former supervisor with this inquiry, but she is presently on maternity leave.  You can give this new prospective supervisor her (work) email address for direct contact and he can also email her if he has an inquiry.  If necessary you can contact your department head (or relevant staff that run the masters program) to obtain assistance in getting an alternative reference.

Comment: Thanks Ben, but is it also inappropriate to give my former supervisor's contact to the new supervisor since she has not actually agreed to be my referee?

Comment: As I understand your question, your prospective supervisor has asked for a reference from your past advisor.  Professional email addresses for academic staff are public knowledge; they are included on staff web-pages, etc.  They are essentially like office phone numbers, etc., so unless there is some countervailing reason to the contrary, you can share them with whoever you want.

Comment: There's a big difference between someone googling your supervisor's email address and you giving that address to them as a reference, though - even if it's a technical difference.

Comment: @Joe, true, though one's former supervisor is (perhaps in perpetuity) in a professional relationship that (as we all know) may involve future employers'/supervisors' inquiries.

Answer (score 6):

> "However, I have her Facebook and Instagram info, so I can message her
> there, but is it appropriate to do so?"

**Yes, it is "appropriate" to do so**. In other words, you would increase the chances of getting a letter if you do so, and only very marginally decrease it. The reason is obvious: you make her understand that it is important to you.

Furthermore, Academia is *not* a usual work-place. It is certainly not a corporate work-place, and for most parts it's not even a "work": many of the major aspects of academic life are on a volunteer basis. Hence, while it may be seen as "unprofessional" to contact your boss on Facebook if you work in a traditional industry/corporate (e.g., insurance company), it is not entirely inappropriate to contact academic colleges on social networks.

Clarifications: it is impossible to know in advance if your supervisor is going to be happy or not to receive your message.

It is also important to understand different cultures, and know where your previous supervisor works: if she is from UK/US, then she may indeed be more inclined to see her job as akin to a "corporate" job, IMO. If she is from Central Europe, she may be less so (again, IMO).